# Hamachi not working properly with PPPoE connections

Tags: linux, debian, vpn

I'm experiencing some troubles running Hamachi VPN alongside with a PPoE connection.

On my linux_machine I have 3 different interfaces:

- eth0: the unconfigured ethernet interface used by ppp0 for enstablish the connection
  (MTU 1500)
- ppp0: the pppoe connection (MTU 1492)
- ham0: the hamachi tun interface (MTU 1404)

My linux_machine connects to the internet via ppp0 but also build a ham0 tun that I can use for connect with the others hamachi vpn machines.

What happen is that **if I use any machine in the hamachi network to connect to linux_machine the connection is very poor and 
even if I can't see from ifconfig packet loss or errors the effects I'm getting are visually the same.**

Things changes if I get rid of ppp0 and keep only eth0 and ham0 interfaces making my pc connect directly via eth0. If I do this, hamachi works flawlessy.

With a friend we started to guess about the possible conversion that hamachi already do from MTU 1500->1404 but is not programmed for do a 1492->1404 conversion.

Some persons also suggests that I can lower the ham0 MTU but I'm not sure this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered why it was not working properly, seemingly my connection was relayed and their servers are pretty full.

I experienced a loot of packet drops that I tough caused by wrong MTU configuration, instead the reason was just that I was using a slow and problematic relay server.

Without the pppoe hamachi gone in direct mode, so the connection was enstablished inside my own lan making me think I had not problems because less MTU conversions.

Seemingly I gone checking for a finer detail problem when there was a bigger one in front of me.